# pgfplots expression with data from data files

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

To add plot using data from an external file, I write something like this

```
\addplot[blue,ultra thick] table[x=freq,y=magS21,col sep=comma] {images/ms.csv};
```

But is there any way to add plot of `10^(magS21/20)` without creating new columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.. I just had to look in pgfplots, not in tikz manual
This is said in chapter

> 4.3.4 Mathematical Expressions And File Data

Here is the way to do this:

```
\addplot[red,ultra thick] table[x=freq,y expr = 10^(\thisrow{dbS21}/20),col sep=comma]{images/ms.csv}; \label{Amplp}
```